# install laravel-echo and pusher-js as a simple js file without using npm

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5.3

To Receiving Broadcasts notifications in **laravel 5.3**, I needed to include **laravel-echo** and **pusher-js** files into my blade templates.

I know that it is possible via **npm** package manager as has been explained in [official laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/broadcasting#installing-laravel-echo) like this :

```
npm install --save laravel-echo pusher-js
```

And then in `resouces/assets/js/app.js` file import it like this :

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'your-pusher-key-here'
});
```

But I have a simple js file that all my scripts are Inside it and I did not use npm in my project and all my javascript files are as **.js**.

I went to [laravel-echo github](https://github.com/laravel/echo) page But I did not find any js formatted file that I can use in my pages.

Is there any way other than npm to include laravel-echo?

**Update:**

I found that above codes are based on **Typescript**.I'm not familiar with Typescript. only I know that it can compile to pure javascript files. I am looking for laravel-echo as a js file that I could include it to my page and use included functions and methods. is it posibble?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's actually possible, but I had the same question as you. I was wirthing my .js files into the public folder. When I tried to add echo, everything went wrong. So, this is my solution, but you will still need to use npm.

1. I took my .js file and move it to `resources\assets\js`
2. Open `resources\assets\js\app.js` and add `require(./filename.js);`
3. run `npm install`
4. run `npm run dev`
5. Change the link to the new `app.js` file into my layout.

That way I managed to keep one js file into my code and use laravel-echo.

Maybe there is another solution, but I did not tried it.

1. Start a new laravel project
2. run `npm install`
3. Modify `webpack.mix.js` the following way:

`mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js').extract(['echo']);`

4. copy the `public/js/vendor.js` file to your actual project.

**Theorically**, this is all the script echo need to be functional. At this point, I think you will need to modify/delete some lines to make it work without the webpack initialisation.